# In the java project with Lombok dependency, faker.options() is showing exception, which basically says options() method is undefined

Tags: java, lombok

Following is the screenshot that I am provided with, and the Project uses java language and Faker is `com.github.javafaker.Faker`:

[image]

Following is the Lombok Builder class, for Event, and the other pojo's are similar so not providing the others:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Builder
public class Event {

    private User user;
    private Product product;



    public Event(User user, Product product) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

When I try to achieve the same functionality, in my local machine, I am getting method options() is undefined.

Please let me know, is options() coming from completely other module?

Here is my local code snippet where I am getting the issue:

[image]

Here is the pom dependency for javafaker:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As I have seen the decompiled java class of Faker, it doesn't have any options() method. So I am wondering from where is that options() method coming from.

Please provide the pom dependency of correct faker class which has options() method in it.

Any clarification will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide the code you are actually using and the exception, both as text.

Comment: And how is Faker defined? Lombok does generate methods, but not an `options` method.

Comment: @Polygnome please let me know, if you need any other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I change the faker dependency, options() seems to work:

Here is the correct dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```